# How do I build the TypeScript compiler (tsc.js) from source?

Tags: typescript, tsc

How do I build the TypeScript compiler (at [typescript.codeplex.com](http://typescript.codeplex.com)) from source? When I clone it from git I see a Makefile, but make in cygwin fails with `*** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?)`

I can't find any clear documentation, and the Readme file in the source doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the makefile with mingw32 or cygwin make, you need to go trough the file and fix the indentation.

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/^[[:space:]]\+/    /" Makefile
```

To get it to compile, you can issue this command:

```
make TYPESCRIPT_HOST="cscript //Nologo" compiler
```

This also works with `nmake`.

Answer (score 3):

The Makefile in the TypeScript source is in NMAKE format and has dependencies on Windows commands. NMAKE comes with Visual Studio and is in the path when you run a Visual Studio Command Prompt.

In order to build you need both nmake and [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) in your path. Then just run:

```
nmake TYPESCRIPT_HOST=node world
```

from the directory containing your TypeScript source. The built `.js` files will be placed in `built\local`

**Edit:** Added the missing arg setting TYPESCRIPT_HOST

Comment: As Markus Jarderot points out you can also use TYPESCRIPT_HOST="cscript //Nologo", which removes the dependency on nodejs. I found that using node makes the build much faster though.

Comment: After building, run `npm install -g` and you have easy access to `tsc`.

Answer (score 1):

There's an even easier answer, apparently. Just referring to tsc.ts in /src/compiler does the trick:

```
tsc tsc.ts --out tsc.js
```

All other files are pulled via ///  syntax automatically.