# How to run tests included with TypeScript sourcecode?

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript](http://typescript.codeplex.com/) comes with the full source code and unit tests.

How do I run these tests? Or is it only by [building the whole thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256885/how-do-i-build-the-typescript-compiler-tsc-js-from-source)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows (preferably a VS2012 or 2010 command prompt, or with suitable stuff on the PATH), run:

`nmake runtests`

You'll need to have the `TYPESCRIPT_HOST` environment variable set to `node` (with node.js installed). Alternatively, `nmake runtests HOST=node`.

You can also run a subset of tests:

`nmake runtests tests=tests\compiler\someVariousTest.ts`

There's also a smaller subset for compiler-only tests:

`nmake runtests-compiler`